# component is showing before its called ,how to fix it

Tags: angular

I have a component which has a modal. My main component is `app.component.html` and this component name is `app-compeleted-component`,so in the routing if you browse http://localhost:4200/ it will show my `app.component.html` which is home page. If you browse http://localhost:4200/app-compeleted-component it should show the page with modal in it. I'm sending some info to this modal component from the main one.

So inside my `app.html.component` I have:

```html
<app-compeleted-component [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-compeleted-component>
```

Since it is inside my `app.component.html` it's showing before its url is hit. I want it to be shown once this  http://localhost:4200/app-compeleted-component is hit ,how can I do that? I'm new to angular. To be honest, I could not find a way for that. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Do not place roted components anywhere. Routing is responsible for showing them. Only thing you need to add inside the app.component.html is `<router-outlet>`.

Also `app.component.html` cannot be your home page since it is the routing root. Create a `home.component` and add following routing setup:

```
routes: Route[] = [
   { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
   { path: 'completed', component: CompletedComponent }
```

That way navigation to `/competed` will hide home component and show modal.

Comment: I have already put everything in my app.component.html and ts,if i create a new component and put them all there,will it work?i mean just need to copay paste?